# How to compile Bootstrap from source as part of build process on heroku?

Tags: node.js, twitter-bootstrap, heroku, npm

I am building a simple node app and using Bootstrap to style my frontend. I want to deploy the app to Heroku by loading it from the GitHub repository. I don't want to put any compiled CSS/JS files in the repository, which means that they need to be compiled on Heroku after the source is pulled from GitHub.

The problem: Bootstrap's default `package.json` has its build dependencies in `devDependencies`, so the dependencies will not be installed on Heroku, which runs `npm install` in production mode.

Specifically, the problem comes up in my `postinstall` script, which consists of `cd node_modules/bootstrap && npm install && ../.bin/grunt dist`. My own `npm install` command does not end up installing anything because the overarching `npm install --production` is ignoring Bootstrap's `devDependencies`.

What is the best workaround to get Bootstrap's dependencies to be installed locally? I'm open to changing my workflow as long as (1) I don't have to put compiled files in my source repository and (2) I can still run the main `npm install` in production mode.

EDIT: Unless someone can think of a better solution, I think my options at this point are as follows:

1. Build a custom Github fork of Bootstrap that has its dependencies in `dependencies` instead of `devDependencies`
2. Build a custom Heroku buildpack that somehow leaves Bootstrap's dependencies intact
3. Abandon principle and compile Bootstrap locally, and put the compiled files in my source
4. Just use Heroku in development mode (obviously not a good idea)

I think I'm going to try for option 1, and go for option 3 if that fails. I'd still be interested in hearing any other ideas that people come up with.

Answer (score 0):

I would look into using `postinstall`. The official documentation is on Heroku [here](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/nodejs-support#customizing-the-build-process).

Comment: Sorry, I've modified my original question to be more clear. I am using `postinstall` to run the Bootstrap installation and compilation. But since the installation is running in production mode, the `--production` flag propogates through to my `postinstall` script and prevents Bootstrap's `devDependencies` from being installed.

Answer (score 0):

Since you're doing some build steps at deploy time, you need some devDependencies (bootstrap sources in your case), but heroku will only install in production mode, like you said.

When connected with the heroku toolbelt client, run :

```
heroku config:set NPM_CONFIG_PRODUCTION=false
```

You'll have your devDependencies and you'll be able to build.

You only have to do that once (no need to do that each time you deploy).

PS: I don't know about your project, but maybe you need to put the `NODE_ENV` to `production`, here is the command:

```
heroku config:set NODE_ENV=production
```

Comment: With `NPM_CONFIG_PRODUCTION` set to `false`, the deploy was built correctly. Unfortunately, once I set it back to `true`, the next deploy will fail because the Heroku buildpack destroys the `node_modules` directory at the beginning of a deploy and rebuilds all dependencies from scratch.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need yo put back the `NPM_CONFIG_PRODUCTION` flag back to true, this is the purpose of making the build on heroku.

But if you prefer, here is the workflow you could use (you said you were opened to change workflow):

- ignore `dist` folder from your source repo (it should already be ignored)
- make `dist` folder a git repo & add the git remote of heroku in repo of the `dist` folder

  - `cd dist`
  - `git init`
  - `git remote add origin git@heroku.com:project-name.git`
  - `git pull origin master`
- make sure your build routine doesn't remove this `/dist/.git` folder - you can use the following glob (if you're using rimraf or something like it with grunt/gulp or whatever) : `['/dist/**/*','/dist/!.git/**/*']`

This way, your workflow will be:

- build (with your tool)
- `cd dist`
- `git add .`
- `git commit -m "new version bundled"`
- `git push origin master` there, you are in `dist` folder where origin is the remote for your heroku

You might do the same kind of things with github pages ...